# how to read data attr in fancybox2 callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I have a simple image gallery with the great [Fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin.

```
<a href="img1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group"><img src="img1.jpg" data-title="Awesome image" alt="image 1"></a>
<a href="img2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group"><img src="img2.jpg" data-title="Good indeed" alt="image 2"></a>
<!-- and so on -->
```

What I'm trying to do is to catch the `data-title` by `beforeShow` callback function of the current Image.

My attempt was:

```
beforeShow : function() {
    var title = this.getAttribute('data-title');
    console.log(title); // nope does not work
}
```

I'm wondering because this doesn't work. Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I also tried `.attr('data-title');` and `.data('title');` but it gives me `undefined`.

**ANSWER:** Okay guys I found it out

```
var title = this.element.find('img').data('title');
```

does the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it out! Post it as an answer and mark it so others can benefit from it! :D This seemed to work too, atleast for the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/00pLzq1x/1/

Comment: @urbz you are not using a `callback` of Fancybox, which is completely different to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so, it seems that `Fancybox`' callback is working with kind of an own `this` element which is why

```
$(this).data('title'); // DOESN'T WORK
```

or

```
$(this).attr('data'); // DOESN'T WORK
```

throws `undefined`. I found the solution in the Documentation:

```
var title = this.element.find('img').data('title');
```